# Teamcity not building compact framework project

Tags: compact-framework, teamcity

I am currently trying to get TeamCity 5.1.2 to build a compact framework project (I am not wanting to build a CAB just build the project)  however I continue to get an error

```
Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.Targets(23, 9): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks.GetDeviceFrameworkPath" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

the .NET Compact Framework(3.5) is installed on the build machine so I am stumped....does anyone have an ideas on a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. My solution was to configure a "Visual Studio 2008" build step in teamcity instead of a "MSBuild" build step.